# How can I use the "which" argument in the "makeA" function in the pedigree package in R to run faster?

Tags: r, performance, large-data

I am using the "makeA" function in R's "pedigree" package to try and create a matrix of coefficients of relatedness between two sheep, based on a pedigree file.

My pedigree file has about 56,000 sheep, of which only about 26,000 are the ones I need coefficients of relatedness for (because they are the only remaining alive sheep).

How would I use the "which" argument to specify that I only want coefficients of relatedness for sheep with "Status" column value of "0" (indicating the animal is alive/at hand)?

I presume if I could do this it would make the function run much faster (at the moment it takes in excess of 30 minutes). Does anyone have any other pointers that may make it quicker? Open to try anything (within  my limited R knowledge).

Here is my code:

```
library(pedigree)
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

ped <- read.csv("ped.csv", header = TRUE)


start <- Sys.time()
makeA(ped,which = c(rep(TRUE,NROW(ped))))
end <- Sys.time()
end - start
```

I have more processing steps later on but I haven't even got past the step of creating the raw matrix for the actual (large) dataset.

Note that for smaller datasets the function works almost instantly.

Comment: hard to say without a reproducible example, but `makeA(ped,which=which(ped$Status==0))` ... ?

Comment: `which` [says its looking for a logical vector](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/pedigree/versions/1.4/topics/makeA), so I think just `makeA(ped, which = ped$Status == 0)` (though the `which()` wrapper might still work).

Comment: oops, yes ......

Comment: Thanks @BenBolker, I'm running it now (taken about 5 mins so far) so will let you know the outcome!

Comment: It's been over 30 minutes and unfortunately no completion! My memory is maxing out so is my disk usage (97% and 99%). This is inspite of my Intel i7 and 16GB RAM. Now I'm really confused!

Comment: Do it in pieces.

Comment: Hmm not sure if that would work as the output is a matrix of coefficients, between each possible pair of animals (in a dataset of 10,000 animals, can have more than 5,000,000 pairs of animals)

Comment: Sorry that ^ should be more like 50 million. Missed a zero

Comment: Suprisingly, I've found that the "makeAinv" function which creates the inverse of the "A matrix" from "makeA," runs in about 1.5 seconds. I figured if I could invert this, then I would get the relationship matrix I am after. Only issue is the matrix is a 3 column list of: ID animal 1, ID animal 2, coefficient of relatedness... somehow need to get this into a matrix format to invert